Element Tree reads only root element without its contents in certain XML files
I need to make a Python script to fetch cameras configurations and check on the stuff wrote in their OSD. I made code that downloads XML file directly from them and then parses through it in order to find the Inventory ID.
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

first_config = """
<VideoOverlay xmlns="http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
<normalizedScreenSize>
<normalizedScreenWidth>704</normalizedScreenWidth>
<normalizedScreenHeight>576</normalizedScreenHeight>
</normalizedScreenSize>
<attribute>
<transparent>false</transparent>
<flashing>false</flashing>
</attribute>
<TextOverlayList size="4">
<TextOverlay>
<id>1</id>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<positionX>0</positionX>
<positionY>576</positionY>
<displayText>Inv: 1234513454321</displayText>
<directAngle/>
</TextOverlay>
</TextOverlayList>
<DateTimeOverlay>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<positionX>552</positionX>
<positionY>560</positionY>
<dateStyle>DD-MM-YYYY</dateStyle>
<timeStyle>24hour</timeStyle>
<displayWeek>false</displayWeek>
</DateTimeOverlay>
<channelNameOverlay>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<positionX>553</positionX>
<positionY>48</positionY>
</channelNameOverlay>
<fontSize>48*48</fontSize>
<frontColorMode>auto</frontColorMode>
<frontColor>000000</frontColor>
<alignment>customize</alignment>
<boundary>1</boundary>
</VideoOverlay>
"""

second_config = """
<VideoOverlay xmlns="http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
<normalizedScreenSize>
<normalizedScreenWidth>704</normalizedScreenWidth>
<normalizedScreenHeight>576</normalizedScreenHeight>
</normalizedScreenSize>
<attribute>
<transparent>false</transparent>
<flashing>false</flashing>
</attribute>
<fontSize>48*48</fontSize>
<TextOverlayList size="8">
<TextOverlay>
<id>1</id>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<positionX>3</positionX>
<positionY>48</positionY>
<displayText>Inv: 100000000</displayText>
<isPersistentText>true</isPersistentText>
</TextOverlay>
<TextOverlay>
<id>2</id>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<positionX>0</positionX>
<positionY>576</positionY>
<displayText>GEO:0000000000</displayText>
<isPersistentText>true</isPersistentText>
</TextOverlay>
<TextOverlay>
<id>3</id>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<positionX>0</positionX>
<positionY>576</positionY>
<displayText>Serial:000000000</displayText>
<isPersistentText>true</isPersistentText>
</TextOverlay>
<TextOverlay>
<id>4</id>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<positionX>0</positionX>
<positionY>576</positionY>
<displayText>MODEL:0000000000000</displayText>
<isPersistentText>true</isPersistentText>
</TextOverlay>
<TextOverlay>
<id>5</id>
<enabled>false</enabled>
<positionX>0</positionX>
<positionY>576</positionY>
<displayText/>
<isPersistentText>true</isPersistentText>
</TextOverlay>
<TextOverlay>
<id>6</id>
<enabled>false</enabled>
<positionX>0</positionX>
<positionY>576</positionY>
<displayText/>
<isPersistentText>true</isPersistentText>
</TextOverlay>
<TextOverlay>
<id>7</id>
<enabled>false</enabled>
<positionX>0</positionX>
<positionY>576</positionY>
<displayText/>
<isPersistentText>true</isPersistentText>
</TextOverlay>
<TextOverlay>
<id>8</id>
<enabled>false</enabled>
<positionX>0</positionX>
<positionY>576</positionY>
<displayText/>
<isPersistentText>true</isPersistentText>
</TextOverlay>
</TextOverlayList>
<DateTimeOverlay>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<positionX>0</positionX>
<positionY>576</positionY>
<dateStyle>DD-MM-YYYY</dateStyle>
<timeStyle>24hour</timeStyle>
<displayWeek>false</displayWeek>
</DateTimeOverlay>
<channelNameOverlay xmlns="http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
<enabled>true</enabled>
<positionX>581</positionX>
<positionY>48</positionY>
</channelNameOverlay>
<frontColorMode>auto</frontColorMode>
<frontColor>000000</frontColor>
<alignment>customize</alignment>
<boundary>1</boundary>
<upDownboundary>0</upDownboundary>
<leftRightboundary>0</leftRightboundary>
</VideoOverlay>
"""

xml_string = first_config

root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
print(root.tag)

osd_list_size = root[2].attrib['size']
print(osd_list_size) #size of the list of OSD lines

for child in root[2]:
    print(child[4].text)

xml_string = second_config

root_b = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
print(root_b.tag)

osd_list_size = root_b[2].attrib['size']
print(osd_list_size) #size of the list of OSD lines

for child in root_b[2]:
    print(child[4].text)

Any ideas why it behaves like that and how can I fix it?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\S26-tech-Dmt\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\Test.py", line 159, in <module>
    osd_list_size = root_b[2].attrib['size']
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'size'

Unfortunately, whenever I try parsing through second_config, it returns empty root Element with no contents in it, since it says that attribute 'size' does not exist. Any idea what might be the problem and how to fix it?

The TextOverlayList element is not at the same position in both XML files, so you should not access it
by position. Use find() to access an element by its name:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def parse_config(xml_string):
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
    print(root.tag)

    uri = 'http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema'

    text_overlay_list = root.find('{%s}TextOverlayList' % uri)
    osd_list_size = text_overlay_list.attrib['size']
    print(osd_list_size) #size of the list of OSD lines

    for child in text_overlay_list:
        display_text = child.find('{%s}displayText' % uri)
        print(display_text.text)

Output when called on the second file:
{http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema}VideoOverlay
8
Inv: 100000000
GEO:0000000000
Serial:000000000
MODEL:0000000000000
None
None
None
None


Thx so much M8.
